# How i can load new elements when my ListView is scrolled to bottom?

Tags: java, android

You can find my code here:
[How to correctly build table with data using onPostExecute and ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048333/how-to-correctly-build-table-with-data-using-onpostexecute-and-listview)

I need to do loading data from the server when my **ListView** is scroll to the bottom. I tried to looking for solution on Stackoverflow, but it is not helpful for me.

Also if it's not difficult i like to know how it's work for understand all.

Thank's to  all

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761639/android-dynamic-loading-list-view-onscrolllistener-issues

Comment: one option is to use OnScrollListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

**1) With OnScrollListener**

You must have a class that extends *ListView* and implements *OnScrollListener*.

When you initialise the view, set it as the scroll listener :
    `setOnScrollListener(this);`

Implement the method `onScroll`. It's called when you scroll with the arguments *firstVisibleItem*, *visibleItemCount* and *totalItemCount*.

When `firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount==totalItemCount` you reached the bottom of the list, you can call your *AsyncTask* again to load the next items.

**2) With a custom adapter**

In the method `getView` that you must overwrite, you have access to the position of the item being rendered, i.e. about to be visible on the screen.

Let's say you store your items in a `List items` you know when you reached the bottom of the list when `position == items.size()-1`. You can then call your *AsyncTask*.

### Warning

Be careful with these 2 solutions, if all the items of the list fit in the screen, your *AsyncTask* may be called very often and for no reason. You must do the necessary checks for that before starting it.

Comment: Thank you! I choose first solution.

Comment: @Philippe A What about reverse Scrolling?

Comment: @AjayTakur you mean when the user is scrolling up ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. In Solution #1, totalItemCount is constant, visibleItemCount is most likely constant too, firstVisibleItem will decrease as you scroll up. In Solution #2 the position will decrease as you scroll up and won't be equal to the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Scroll state change listener in your program...I hope It will help you definitely ....

```
 listStudies.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (Logic Condition) {
                //Here also You can do your Logic here and then you can achieve your wishes.....
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
             if (Logic Condition) {
                //You just do your Logic here and then you can achieve your wishes.....
            }

        }
    });
```